# Can I use a variable in a file path in bash? If so, how?

Tags: bash, filepath

I'm trying to write a small shell script to find the most recently-added file in a directory and then move that file elsewhere.  If I use:

```
ls -t ~/directory | head -1
```

and then store this in the variable VARIABLE_NAME, why can't I then then move this to ~/otherdirectory via:

```
mv ~/directory/$VARIABLE_NAME ~/otherdirectory
```

I've searched around here and Googled, but there doesn't seem to be any information on using variables in file paths?  Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Here's the portion of the script:

```
ls -t ~/downloads | head -1
read diags
mv ~/downloads/$diags ~/desktop/testfolder
```

Comment: Yes you can use variables in path. That isn't necessarily the issue you encountered. You may be encountering some issues such as expansion of `~`. Or you may be having issue with file names and directory names containing space. I am not a mind reader so I wouldn't necessarily know what errors you got when you attempted it.

Comment: What does $VARIABLE_NAME contain?

Comment: I've updated the post with the script portion that handles storing/moving the variable.

Comment: The portion of the script is unsufficient, as it does not show how VARIABLE_NAME receives its value.  Moreover, it would be helpful if you described the observed effect: Did you get an error message, or did the file show up in a different place?

Comment: The first portion of the script (not posted) creates a couple directories in /desktop and runs fine. When I get to the point where I'm moving the file, it seems like the script just hangs and nothing actually happens.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do the following in your script:

```
diags=$(ls -t ~/downloads | head -1)
mv ~/downloads/"$diags" ~/desktop/testfolder
```

In this case, `diags` is assigned the value of `ls -t ~/downloads | head -1`, which can be called on by `mv`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this; ended up being the correct way to handle this after I figured out the subshell problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands

```
ls -t ~/downloads | head -1
read diags
```

are probably not what you intend: the read command does not receive its input from the command before.  Instead, it waits for input from stdin, which is why you believe the script to 'hang'.  Maybe you wanted to do the following (at least this was my first erroneous attempt at providing a better solution):

```
ls -t ~/downloads | head -1 | read diags
```

However, this will (as mentioned by alvits) also not work, because each element of the pipe runs as a separate command: The variable diags therefore is not part of the parent shell, but of a subprocess.

The proper solution therefore is:

```
diags=$(ls -t ~/downloads | head -1)
```

There are, however, further possible problems, which would make the subsequent mv command fail:

- The directory might be empty.
- The file name might contain spaces, newlines etc.

Comment: This piping has helped, but I seem to have transferred the entirety of the downloads directory into the testfolder now.  It looks like $diags is being ignored by the mv command.

Comment: Try running bash in debug mode, that is with bash -x.  You can also put the -x in the shebang line: #/bin/bash -x

Comment: @TheVideotapes - This is a very well known issue with using variables within a sub-shell or pipes. The local variable `$diags` was assigned the output of `ls -t ~/downloads | head -1`, however, it was lost after the execution of the line. You should use `printf -v diag '%s' $(ls -t ~/downloads | head -1)`.

Comment: @alvits - Oops, certainly you are right, will fix that part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks both of you!  A friend showed me http://www.shellcheck.net/ and it saw the subshell issue right away, so I was able to figure this out.  I ended up with `diags=$(ls -t ~/downloads | head -1)` and this was respected in `mv -v ~/downloads/"$diags" ~/desktop/testfolder`